# How to create an horiztonal list in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I have a several images that I want to put in an horizontal list.
Do you know, how I can do that ?
Which component must I use ?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a 'container' with a layout of type 'column'.  If you could make the question a little more specific maybe I could make my answer a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha touch 2 has an ability to display horizontal list.
This might help:

http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-horizontal/